# Win7 Login Screen: Animation / Password box Location Change

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Is there a way on the login screen:

1. to make the background an animation (e.g. from a GIF or AVI file)?
2. to change the users, buttons and password box's location not to be in the middle of the screen?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/617378/windows-7-logon-ui-image-files-how-to-locate-and-edit-them 1. no ... 2. yes